# How to install setproctitle on windows?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install the `openopt` library for Python 3.3 on my Windows 8.1 64 bits.

The thing is, to run its installation I first have to install `setproctitle`.

This is where it all goes wrong.

When I run `easy_install setproctitle`, I get the following error in PowerShell:

> Searching for setproctitle Reading
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/setproctitle/ Best match: setproctitle
>   1.1.8 Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setproctitle/setproctitle-1.1.8.zip#md5=99bd5957546846660a61f30bb8
>   7ba24a Processing setproctitle-1.1.8.zip Writing
>   c:\users\smaga\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-wuzmf5\setproctitle-1.1.8\setup.cfg
>   Running setproctitle-1.1.8\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir
>   c:\users\smaga\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-wuzmf5\setpro
>   ctitle-1.1.8\egg-dist-tmp-z2vmaj Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python33\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('setuptools==1.4.2', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 1924, in main
>
> File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 1911, in with
>   _ei_usage   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 1928, in    File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py",
>   line 148, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 929, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 374, in run   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 609, in easy_ install   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 639, in insta ll_item   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 825, in insta ll_eggs   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 1031, in buil d_and_install   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 1016, in run_ setup   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 69, in run_setup   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 120, in run   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py",
>   line 71, in    File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\compat.py",
>   line 94, in execfile   File "setup.py", line 99, in    File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 929, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 185, in run   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 171, in call_com mand   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py",
>   line 313, in run_command
>       self.distribution.run_command(command)   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\install_lib.py",
>   line 20, in run   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
>       self.run_command('build_ext')   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>       self.distribution.run_command(command)   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 52, in run   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 353, in run
>       self.build_extensions()   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 462, in
>   build_extensions
>       self.build_extension(ext)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\setuptools-1.4.2-py3.3.egg\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 186, in build_ex tension   File
>   "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 517, in
>   build_extension
>       depends=ext.depends)   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
>       self.initialize()   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
>       vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)   File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in
>   query_vcvarsall
>       raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys()))) ValueError: ['path']

I searched around on SO and on the internet, and I reckong that the problem is coming from `msvc9compiler.py`.

I made sure that I have the Visual Studio 9 compiler installed on the machine, but I really don't know how to go from there...

Has anybody successfully installed this lib on Windows 8.1 64 bits? Is this a global problem or really specific to my machine where I need to perform some operations?

Answer (score 7):

I used above Answer but the execution method was little different. Please check below,

After downloading the "whl" file from "[Python extension packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setproctitle)"

I chose the first one " setproctitle‑1.1.8‑cp26‑none‑win32.whl ", because my version of python is 2.6 on Windows machine.

And run the file using "pip" installer like below,

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\gctools>pip install "C:\Users\TC3234\Downloads\setproctitle-1.1.8-cp26-none-win32.whl"
Unpacking c:\users\TC3234\downloads\setproctitle-1.1.8-cp26-none-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: setproctitle
Successfully installed setproctitle
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 5):

Although I haven't been able to successfully compile the package from source, there are pre-compiled wheels available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setproctitle.

To use them, download the wheel corresponding to the version of Python you have, and then run, for example:

```
pip install setproctitle‑1.1.8‑cp33‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use the precompiled wheel for Python 3.8 or your own python version.

Steps:

1. Check your python version `$python -V`
2. Download the pre-compiled wheel from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setproctitle](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#setproctitle).
   Mine was
   `setproctitle‑1.2.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl`
3. `pip install "<fileFullPath>/setproctitle‑1.2.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl"`

It will than install the setproctitle.
Then you can install what ever you were trying. I was trying to install airflow.

4. `pip install apache-airflow[postgres,slack,celery]==1.10.14`